# How to include node title in teaser

Tags: nodes, search, display-suite

I am using Display Suit module to enhance the apache solr search results page. I use the Teaser view mode, but I don't get the node title in the teaser, because the node Title field is not available in the Content type display setting under teaser settings.

Is there any alternative way to add the node title as part of teaser view?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even when Display Suite is enabled, you need to set a layout for it to be enabled for that particular content type. If you just want one column you can select the "One Column" and it will add all the fields available with Display Suite.

It should look something like this:
[image]

Comment: Yes, I have it, but now I don't understand how to add title field as part of node teaser.

Comment: It should automatically be added once you chose a DS layout from the list. You drag it out of the "hidden" or "disabled" section up in the "content" or other section you want to place it in.

Comment: Hi @CarolineCB,

There is a problem, I get this below error on the search results page: Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in _uc_attribute_alter_form() (line 1429 of /sites/all/modules/ubercart/uc_attribute/uc_attribute.module).

Comment: I'm sorry I don't have ubercart. Did you try an open the uc_attributes.module file and go see what's at line 1429?

Comment: I think the problem is with DS module it self... please follow below link to add a patch and fix the error:
https://drupal.org/node/1950660